# Getting error at server and working fine at localhost, Laravel CTE (Adjacency)

Tags: php, mariadb, common-table-expression

I am getting below error at server but working fine at localhost. I am using laravel Adjacency list https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive `laravel_cte` as ((select *, 1 as `depth`, cast(`id` as char(65535)) a' at line 1 (SQL: with recursive `laravel_cte` as ((select *, 1 as `depth`, cast(`id` as char(65535)) as `path` from `user_relations` where `user_relations`.`parent_id` = 10000 and `user_relations`.`parent_id` is not null) union all (select `user_relations`.*, `depth` + 1 as `depth`, concat(`path`, '.', `user_relations`.`id`) from `user_relations` inner join `laravel_cte` on `laravel_cte`.`id` = `user_relations`.`parent_id`)) select count(`id`) as aggregate from `laravel_cte` where `status` = 0)
```

Please help me to solve it, I am clueless as I am new to this type of complex mySQL/MariaDB development.

Comment: What is your local and your production mariadb version? (The error message indicates mariadb, not mysql. They are very similar, but not the same)

Comment: @Shadow thank you, I have updated the server MariaDB version, and it worked fine. Plz post is an answer. you have saved my lots of hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"CTE" (`WITH RECURSIVE ...`) is not available until MariaDB 10.2 or MySQL 8.0.